# How to reuse UIControl from iPhone xib to iPad xib

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xib

I am converting my application into Universal, So I have created iPad xib with ~ipad.xib extension. Now I want to use all the old UIControls used in iPhone.xib in iPad.xib without recreating and connecting, Is there any way to reuse it? I have checked in one SO question he mentioned copied and used it in iPad. How to do it?

Comment: Can you just select all, copy, and paste? That might lose the connections.

Comment: Ya, what can I do for that?Any way?

Comment: I have changed the class name in identity inspector, Now I can connect all my outlets, But any idea to bypass this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First take back up of your application.GO to your app target section and right click there  u will get three option like **Duplicate**, **Delete**, **Project Editor Help**....Now Select Duplicate it will show alert like below image.[image] Now select **"Duplicate and Transition to iPad"**.Xcode will generate all xib's for iPad with connections.Copy all xibs of iPad to original application.

Comment: I did like what you said, some xibs are still looking like iPhone xib.. What could be the problem?

Comment: Action sheet also not showing properly, I have given three option it showing only two.. in the middle as you said, How to make it normal for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

just select all controls make copy & paste in new .Xib .

Comment: I tried, it is copying however that are not properly visible for iPad xib.. Other than copy, paste anything Am I missing?